# How to read image from folder upload in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to use webkitdirectory to send multiple XHTML requests, each with an image an supporting information.

If I remove webkitdirectory and just use 'multiple' it works fine.

However, as soon as I try to read the images from a folder, it errors saying "can  not find file".

**Code**

JavaScript
(I have removed some element to simplify)

```
function getData() {
    var formEle = document.getElementById("form");
    var fileList = document.getElementById("files"); 
    var fileList = fileList.files
    var respEle = document.getElementById("resp"); 

    for(var i = 0; i< fileList.length; i++){

        (function(i) {

            var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

            var formData = new FormData(formEle); 
            var _jsonBody = [{ 
                original_filename: fileList[i].name, 
                category_id : 2
            }]; 

            formData.append("file", fileList[i]); 
            formData.append("_jsonBody", JSON.stringify(_jsonBody)); 

            xhr.open("POST", url);  
            xhr.send(formData);

            xhr.addEventListener("loadend", loadEnd, false);

            console.log(xhr);

            function loadEnd(e) {

                if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 201) {
                    var response = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
                    respEle.innerHTML = respEle.innerHTML + '<br>Well done: '+ response.original_filename + ' added';
                }else{
                    var response = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
                    respEle.innerHTML = respEle.innerHTML + '<br>Error: ' + response.error_message;
                }
            }
        })(i);    
    }
    return false; 
}
```

HTML

```
<form id="form" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" onsubmit="return getData();"> 
    <input id="files" name="file" type="file" multiple webkitdirectory directory > <br><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Upload File"><br><br>
</form> 

<div id="resp"></div>
```

Comment: you need server sided or by guessing in js? :/

Comment: Just need to send the file, the 3rd API processes it